# TFS: How to restore merge-ability after someone Deleted and Re-Added instead of Moved a file?

Tags: java, tfs

A developer, while extracting some functionality from a larger project out into a separate new smaller project, unfortunately Deleted the existing file, and then Added that same file into the new location. (Better alternative would have been to do a Move, so TFS knows the history).

Some time later, in a maintenance branch, the original file has been updated with some new functionality.

When I try to merge those changes into the branch where the file was deleted and then added elsewhere, TFS (rightfully) says the file has been deleted, and offers no help with the merge.

Is there were some way to teach TFS that the file was really just moved? (Aside from rolling back the Delete/Add and performing a Move)

Comment: Which one are you merging back to? The old location with deleted file or the new location with re-added file?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Merging from another branch where the old location is still intact, to the newer branch where the old location has since been deleted.

Comment: Is it a baseless merge? I create a test in TFS2015 with baseless merge, it works well, you just need to resolve conflicts. However, in TFS 2010, the original file and the re-added file maybe not having merge relationship. For this situation, you  may either roll back or merge the newer branch to the maintenance branch  to add that file and do the changes on the new added file , discard the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have deleted the old file and readd the same file. However in TFS, this is totally a new file, and this operation will losing history with the new added file. Next time when you accidentally delete  a file in TFS, you can [restore a item deleted from server.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders#restore-an-item-deleted-from-the-server)

---

**Update**

For your situation, the original file and the re-added file maybe not having merge relationship. For this situation, you  may either roll back or merge the newer branch to the maintenance branch  to add that file and do the changes on the new added file , discard the original file.